# Is it possible to have infected Computer A infect Computer B whilst being only connected by an Ethernet cable?

Tags: malware, worm

Is it possible to have infected Computer A infect Computer B whilst being only connected by an Ethernet cable?

My current research into worms is that they always seem to require an additional vector in order to propagate. For example DorkBot spreads through USBs. Other vectors include email servers and SMB/Net shares.

Computer A and Computer B are both Windows 10 machines. Computer A is already infected. The goal is to infect Computer B. They are connected to each other via Ethernet cable.

If anyone has any examples or code downloads I would be very appreciative. Note this is for a project and not for malicious use.

Comment: Have you heard of Wannacry? Ransomware?

Comment: "email servers and SMB/Net shares" are an ethernet vectors ... It's possible you have a misunderstanding somewhere or your definitions are not quite right.

Comment: why don't you think a network is a vector?